# Rails controller: authenticating only for certain actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails site with users, and these users can make certain pages.

I am trying to make those pages viewable to people not logged in. So, I am making another view & controller action for the page.

Currently, the only issue I have is making a controller that has one action that requires authentication and another action which does not, while remaining on the same controller.

**What I have**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    respond_to :json


    def show 
        @page = Page.new
        ....
    end
    ....
 end
```

**What I want**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
    if params[:action] != 'show_public'
        before_action :authenticate_user!
        skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    end
    respond_to :json



    def show 
        @page = Page.new
        @current_user = current_user
        ....
    end

    def show_public
        @page = Page.new
        ....
    end
    ....
 end
```

The error which I currently get is:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for PagesController:Class
```

**Note**

Someone else made most of the code for this site (and has since left), and I am new to rails. So, if I am going about solving this problem with the entirely wrong approach please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]
```

So this will run only on `show` action. Sometimes you need to run on all and leave one so:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
```

So this will not run on `show` but will run on all other actions. And suppose your `before_action` is in application controller and you need to skip in the inherited controllers you can do it like this:

```
skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:show]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to authenticate for everything but show_public?